# Error: Body must be a string. Received: undefined. - When using Amplify, AppSync, and GraphQL from React/NextJS client

Tags: javascript, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

When I try to make a call from my front-end (NextJS) I get the following error `Error: Body must be a string. Received: undefined.`

I can successfully make a call from my AppSync console, but not from my front-end. I have pushed the following `schema.graphql` file with `amplify push`:

```
type Mutation {
...
  cancelCard(input: CancelCardInput!): AWSJSON
    @function(name: "myp-service-prod-cancel-stepfunction-lambda")
}
```

I'm seeing logs in CloudWatch when I trigger the Lambda from the Lambda and AppSync consoles, but something is blocking the calls from my javascript:

```js
import { cancelCard } from "../src/graphql/mutations";

    const lambdaResponse = await API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(cancelCard, {
        input: { id: cardId },
      })
    )
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem was that I had performed `amplify codegen configure` and updated from javascript to typescript. As a result, Amplify had updated my `src/` folder to have `.ts` files in, but not removed the `.js` files. This meant that where I had:

- src/graphql/

  - mutations.ts
  - mutations.js

My app was ignoring the mutations.ts file.

Deleting the js files solved the issue.